# Finding common rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server

SQL

I have a list of teams and who they played, and the score of a game.

- rid (Unique to Game)
- hid(unique to home)
- vid (unique to visitor)

Sample data:

```
rid gamedate    hid home    Home Score  vid visitor Visitor Score
------------------------------------------------------------------    
183 08/31/2017  4   Aliso           3   15  Beck        2
261 09/20/2017  4   Aliso           12  137 Mission     2
306 09/19/2017  4   Aliso           10  194 San         9
211 08/25/2017  25  Burrou          14  137 Mission     7
161 09/05/2017  25  Burrou          16  15  Beck        18
203 08/26/2017  25  Burrou          6   388 Pal         20
187 08/31/2017  7   Martin Luther   3   15  Beck        2
```

What I am trying to do is create a query to select 'home' teams that have a 'visitor' team in common.  Meaning, teams that have played against a similar opponent.

I have tried intersect, but am not quite clear how to use it in this unique situation.  The end result would look like this:

```
rid gamedate    hid home    Home Score  vid visitor Visitor Score
-----------------------------------------------------------------    
183 08/31/2017  4   Aliso           3   15  Beck        2
187 08/31/2017  7   Martin Luther   3   15  Beck        2
161 09/05/2017  25  Burrou          16  15  Beck        18
261 09/20/2017  4   Aliso           12  137 Mission     2
211 08/25/2017  25  Burrou          14  137 Mission     7
```

After I am able to discern what teams have played a similar team with the results, I think I can take it from there to work with the data.

I am completely new to the though of using intersect.

Thank you for taking a moment to look at this.

Comment: Thank you marc_s.  I knew my editing didn't look right.

Comment: Hi, i didnt check that the last data row "4 - Martin Luther" has the same id than Aliso > 4.

Comment: Thank you Juan, I made the edit to reflect that the ID is unique.  It should have been unique.

Comment: rid has duplicate data too (211)... in the second table.

Comment: argh...apologies.

Comment: Burrou didnt play with Beck, in first table, we maybe need to go chat.

Comment: Data updated with correct data.  Again, apologies.

Comment: take a look to my answer, change data columns names like your real table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using intersect:

Using a join and anything else:

```
select d.* from
(
    select a.rid, a.hid,a.home,a.vid,a.visitor from matches a
    inner join matches b
    on a.vid = b.vid
    group by a.rid,a.hid,a.home,a.vid,a.vid,a.visitor
    having count(*) > 1
) c
inner join matches d
on c.rid = d.rid
```

Comment: In SQL, it appears that joining matches A & B needs something other than a 'where' clause.  I get 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' error.

Comment: Your answer is perfect.  My data is setup bad in my DB, but I see where this is going.  I thank you.  I don't think I could have thought this up.

Comment: I will appreciate if you can mark as answer, with the check, i read that you want to use intersect, but there is no way with intersect, maybe with except... (i think so).